# Errors "overflow encountered in matmul" and "Optimization failed to converge" while trying to use statsmodels' Exponential smoothing

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have the following series:

```
month,demand
2022-02-01,6059
2022-03-01,11990
2022-04-01,6586
2022-05-01,7363
2022-06-01,10837
2022-07-01,2268
2022-08-01,2615
2022-09-01,1590
2022-10-01,3797
2022-11-01,2195
2022-12-01,4480
2023-01-01,4030
2023-02-01,3242
2023-03-01,3111
2023-04-01,6724
2023-05-01,8781
2023-06-01,3115
2023-07-01,2031
2023-08-01,2992
2023-09-01,1453
2023-10-01,1407
2023-11-01,1672
2023-12-01,3261
2024-01-01,3076
```

And while trying to run the following code:

```py
demands = pd.read_csv('demands.csv')
demands.set_index("month", inplace=True)
demands.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(demands.index.values, freq="MS")

model = sm.tsa.ExponentialSmoothing(demands['demand'], trend='mul', use_boxcox=False)
fittedModel = model.fit()
result = fittedModel.forecast(steps=3),

print(fittedModel.mle_retvals)
```

I get the following warnings:

```
[...]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters/model.py:83: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in matmul
  return err.T @ err
[...]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters/model.py:917: ConvergenceWarning: Optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals.
  warnings.warn(
 message: Inequality constraints incompatible
 success: False
  status: 4
     fun: 287177206.01341003
       x: [ 5.000e-03  1.000e-04  1.019e+04  9.679e-01]
     nit: 2
     jac: [-2.500e+09 -4.295e+05  7.745e+04  9.093e+09]
    nfev: 20
    njev: 2
```

However I could not find anything that would suit why the warnings are being emitted.

Can the warnings impact the forecasted values or are they just something that should be ignored?